# Opencart retriving data from 2 tables

Tags: mysql, sql, opencart, join

I´m trying to join 2 tables in opencart to make an sales report that specifies taxes (by class, there can be many tax%) for every order. I can only get the values from 1 table, but not 2.

How should I do this?

```
<?php   $query = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM `" . DB_PREFIX . "order`, `" .     DB_PREFIX . "order_total`");

$ordersr = array();

// Check if there are any rows returned from the query
if ($query->num_rows > 0) {
// Loop through the returned rows for processing
foreach ($query->rows as $result) {
    $ordersr[] = array(
        'order_id'        => $result['order_id'],
        'invoice_no'      => $result['invoice_no'],
        'total'           => $result['total'],
        'order_status_id' => $result['order_status_id'],
        'date_added'      => $result['date_added'],
        'date_modified'   => $result['date_modified'],
        'firstname'       => $result['firstname'],
        'lastname'        => $result['lastname'],
        'payment_country' => $result['payment_country'],
        'payment_method'  => $result['payment_method'],
        'payment_code'    => $result['payment_code'],
        'shipping_method' => $result['shipping_method'],
        'shipping_code'   => $result['shipping_code'],
        'currency_code'   => $result['currency_code'],
        'currency_value'  => $result['currency_value'],
        'order_status_id' => $result['order_status_id'],
        'date_payed'      => $result['date_payed']
    );
}
} ?>
```

Comment: Don't do `Select *`, and actually list the columns you need.  You should also look into doing an actual `Join`, rather than just listing multiple tables in the `From` clause.

Comment: You are talking about *joining* but you are not using `JOIN` in your query. How those two tables relate? I don't see any `WHERE` clause either. And where exactly is the problem (except the query's purpose itself is kind of unclear to me)?

Comment: When i look at the built in reports, I don´t either see any joins, so could it be possible to do it without a join? And it should be where order.order_id = order_total.order_id?